# How can I directly edit the filesystem of a flash drive / flash card?

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, mbr, filesystem-corruption

I have an inaccessible SD card, and I need to manually rewrite the tables for the filesystem.

Is there a method I can use to directly edit these file system tables in Windows 8? It should preferably also allow me to alter single sectors.

Comment: Specify your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is the tool you need (if you use Windows).

> HxD is a carefully designed and fast hex editor which, additionally to
>   raw disk editing and modifying of main memory (RAM), handles files of
>   any size.
>
> The easy to use interface offers features such as searching and
>   replacing, exporting, checksums/digests, insertion of byte patterns, a
>   file shredder, concatenation or splitting of files, statistics and
>   much more.
>
> Editing works like in a text editor with a focus on a simple and
>   task-oriented operation, as such functions were streamlined to hide
>   differences that are purely technical. For example, drives and memory
>   are presented similar to a file and are shown as a whole, in contrast
>   to a sector/region-limited view that cuts off data which potentially
>   belongs together. Drives and memory can be edited the same way as a
>   regular file including support for undo. In addition memory-sections
>   define a foldable region and inaccessible sections are hidden by
>   default.

Comment: @DaveRook thanks for the edit! I'll keep that in mind, for future answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows, [WinHex](http://winhex.com/winhex/) is an nice choice. See [features](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/allfeatures.html).

> - **Viewing, editing, and repairing system areas**
>
>   such as the Master Boot Record with its partition table and boot sectors. Tools | Disk Editor | Access button

[image: WinHex disk editor]

WinHex contains [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record) [templates](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/templates.html), so when you browsing the MBR using template, it will show a window with many editable input boxes and their descriptions.

[image: WinHex MBR template]

---

If you're using Linux, you can try [hexedit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit), it's a command line tool with text user interface.

Basic shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>: save and exit
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: exit without saving

[image: linux hexedit]